# Update attribute with ajax call rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I appreciate that there may be many answers out there but if there are i cant quite interpret them to suit my needs..I am looking to update a records attribute in my model using ajax.

In my case the attribute selected: true

In my scenario i am clicking on an element and looking to update that elements record in the model

```
<ul class="components">
 <% @component.each do |c| %>
  <li id="<%= c.component_name %>" data-id="<%= c.id %>" data-remote="true"><%= c.component_name %></li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('#Literacy, #Numeracy').on('click', function(){

  var component_name = $(this).text();
  var component_id = $(this).data('id');
  data_send = { id: component_id }

  $.ajax({
   method: 'put',
   url: '/components/selected_component',
    data: data_send,
     success: function(data) {
     console.log(data)
    }
 });
});
```

Controller

```
def selected_component
 @component = Component.find(params[:id])
 @component.update_attributes(selected: true)
end
```

Maybe im looking at this incorrectly but how can i get the id via the click event (stored as component_id) into my selected_component method

Im missing a few bits here but struggling with what today

At the moment I am getting an error

```
Missing template components/selected_component
```

but i dont want to render that page after successful update, I just want to stay on the same page

EDIT

to solve my issue i just had to add this to my format.js

```
{ render nothing: true }
```

Answer (score 1):

A missing template error corresponds to not having a view that knows what to do when it gets a JavaScript request.

In your `views/components/`, just make an `selected_components.js.erb` file and that should clear the error you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I was hoping to achieve this with an on click event , i have updated my question with the error i currently get

Comment: Just updated, if you get more errors after this just leave another comment and I'll get back to you.

Comment: ah actually i need to reload my @strands instance variable without reloading the whole page..any ideas?

Comment: In the template and the ```responds_to``` ```format.js``` block, just add the new instance variable, use the response template to change the variable in the html with something like ```$('selector').data('attr').val('<%= @variable %>')```.